# javascript pass a variable to another page

Tags: javascript

Ok, Here is what I want to do. I have a very complex database. I am reading from the database using php and store the data in a variable (Ajax). Now when I go to another page I loose the variable.

Here is what I know (not sure how correct I am): the scope of a variable is the function it is in. If not specified the scope will be the window object (which changes for every page). Is there any higher level than window? (something like session in php but in the client side)

Comment: You can use webstorage. http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: @AndersonGreen That's very shallow of you.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol What am I missing, then? I wish I understood this question better: I'm a bit confused by its wording.

Comment: @AndersonGreen Zer02 got it right away: use `localStorage`. That said, of course, http://w3fools.com/

Comment: Is it under 5 Mb in size? Why not use a session cookie - it'll be removed on browser close.

Comment: Yes it should be under 5 Mb

Comment: After thinking about it, session cookie would be a really easy implementation - but honestly `localStorage` would be the correct way to go about it. it'd be redundant to use the cookie, but if you really want to explore that route check out [jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) because it makes cookies really simple. (session cookie is one you don't specify an expiration to, it'll remove itself on browser close)

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to storage your variable such as:

1. Use client cookie
2. Use server session or cookie
3. HTML5 storage
4. Query string such as `?var1=blah&var2=blah`

Comment: Bad idea. Unless you like wasting bandwidth.

Comment: Ye-e-e-es... cookies are sent to the server with every single request.

Comment: Erm... it's... that's what cookies are *for*: sending data to the server with each request...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use cookie. Actually php sessions also utilize cookie as well. As far as I know the scope beyong window is cookie.

Or you can use some HTML5 technologies, such as `WebStorage`, but that may break on some old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would avoid storing state in javascript and instead cache the result on the server. Some sort of application or user level cache might be recommended in this case, so that the other page may benefit from the db result. If it's per user then I would look into session. Otherwise it might be better to store it at the application level in some sort of cache